# Is the row key of HBase Table automatically indexed?

Tags: indexing, key, hbase

This may be a silly question - but I couldn't find out how to "index" the row key in Hbase so I am assuming that when HBase puts in the row key they have built-in support to automatically index the table based on the row key - in other words, treating the row key as primary key automatically?

thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The table is not just indexed by the key it is actually lexicographically ordered by the key. i.e. Hbase knows on which region service to find each key and within that regionserver the region and the sepecific HFile. The data that is written to the HFile is ordered by the key.

The lexicographic ordering means you can also retrive data by partial key (e.g. a scan for "a") will get everything that starts with "a". This is used a lot of time to put multiple dimensions in the key e.g. you can have the key set to country followed by city to get aggregates per country and then get a breakdown by city efficiently.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, the tables are ordered via the row key.  And clients can get the region server ids that contain the range of row keys, allowing then to connect directly to the region server that contains the row key that they require.  Furthermore, since the keys are ordered byte arrays, the region server can do a binary search to retrieve the row from list of rows that it contains.  This makes random retrieval very efficient, and it makes scanning contiguous rows very efficient.